# php foreachloop with html tables

Tags: php, http, foreach

I have a foreach loop for 'n' number of cubicles.
I want to display 4 cubicles in each row and reaminig in next row.
How to limit 4 cubicles in each row within foreach loop.

Right now below code display all cubicles in one row

```
  print '<table border="2">';
  print '<tr>';
 foreach($Cubicle as $cubicle )
   {
    print '<td>';

        if($nodeStatus == '0'){
            printf('<a href= "#"  style="color: green; font-weight:bold" onClick="showDetails(\'%s\');">%s</a> ', $nodeId,$insert);
        }
        elseif($nodeStatus == '1'){
            printf('<a href= "#"  style="color: #AF7817; font-weight:bold" onClick="showDetails(\'%s\');">%s</a> ', $nodeId,$insert);
        }
        else{
            printf('<a href= "#"  style="color: RED; font-weight:bold" onClick="showDetails(\'%s\');">%s</a> ', $nodeId,$insert);
        }   

        print '</td>';

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 print '<table border="2">';
 print '<tr>';
 foreach($Cubicle as $num => $cubicle )
 {
   if ($num%4 == 0)
   {
     print '</tr><tr>';
   }
   print '<td>';
   ...
```

Comment: assuming `$num` is numeric... and gap-less

Comment: and start with 0 plus an empty row at the top.

Comment: (1) The first iteration would generate an extra blank row.  You'd have to see if `$num%4 == 3` (rather than 0) in order to make it work.

Comment: (2) What Yanick said.  :)  Though an array of records will often use sequential numeric keys, the few times it doesn't will leave you wondering WTF is messing up your tables.

Comment: @Yanick, yes, but something tells me `$Cubicle` is not an associative array... we'll se if i was right :)

Comment: @k102: I'm only semi correct.  :)  The `</tr><tr>` would need to be printed after the cell, lest the first row only have 3 cells.  And it'd still generate a blank row at the end, if the number of elements is a multiple of 4.  `if ($num != 0 && $num%4 == 0)` would actually work better, i think..then you could keep the code as is (again, assuming the indexes aren't funky).

Comment: Until it doesn't any longer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`array_chunk` <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to obtain the 4 values per each row:

```
 echo '<table border="2">';
 foreach(array_chunk($Cubicle, 4) as $row )
 {
   echo '<tr>';
   foreach($row as $col)
   {
     echo '<td>', $col /* your column formatting */, '</td>';
   }
   echo '</tr>';
  }
 echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print '<table border="2">';
print '<tr>';
$cellIndex = 0;
foreach($Cubicle as $cubicle )
{
   if ((++$cellIndex % 4) == 0) {
      print '</tr><tr>';
   }
   print '<td>';
   ...
```

Comment: using this i get empty row balnk :(

Comment: the test may have needed to be wrapped in parenthesis, I modified the answer to take into account that maybe the test was trying `if (val % 0)`. In any case, depending on the array indexes is not a good idea, since PHP arrays don't have to have contiguous key indexes...

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, and is flexible:

```
function printTable($cubicles, $items_per_row) {
    print '<table border="2">';
    while($row = array_splice($cubicles, 0, $items_per_row)) {
        print '<tr>';
        printRow($row, $items_per_row);
        print '</tr>';
    }
    print '</table>';
}

function printRow($cubicles, $items_per_row) {
    for($i=0; $i<$items_per_row; $i++) {
        print '<td>';
        print (isset($cubicles[$i]) ? $cubicles[$i] : '&nbsp;');
        print '</td>';
    }
}

printTable($Cubicle, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
print '<table border="2">';

$s=0;
foreach($Cubicle as $cubicle )
{
    if($s == 0){
        echo $open_tr = '<tr>';
    }else if($s % ceil(count($Cubicle)/4) == 0){
        echo $open_ul = '</tr><tr>';
    }else{
        echo $open_ul = '';
    }
    print '<td>';

    if($nodeStatus == '0'){
        printf('<a href= "#"  style="color: green; font-weight:bold" onClick="showDetails(\'%s\');">%s</a> ', $nodeId,$insert);
    }
    elseif($nodeStatus == '1'){
        printf('<a href= "#"  style="color: #AF7817; font-weight:bold" onClick="showDetails(\'%s\');">%s</a> ', $nodeId,$insert);
    }
    else{
        printf('<a href= "#"  style="color: RED; font-weight:bold" onClick="showDetails(\'%s\');">%s</a> ', $nodeId,$insert);
    }   

    print '</td>';

    if($s == (count($Cubicle) - 1)){
        echo '</tr>';
        $s++;
    }

}
```

Comment: this prints all cubicles in one coloumn only  :(

Answer (score 1):

The basic technique consist on using a numeric counter to keep track of the column and the modulus operator to keep it in within the column range. Also, since it's an HTML table you may also want to fill missing cells so the display looks good.

Here's an example:

```
<?php

define('NUM_COLUMNS', 4);

$cubicle = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');

if( empty($cubicle) ){
    echo '<p>No cubicles found.</p>';

}else{
    echo '<table>' . PHP_EOL;

    $column = 0;
    foreach($cubicle as $cubicle_name){
        if( $column==0 ){
            echo '<tr>';
        }

        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($cubicle_name) . '</td>';

        if( $column==NUM_COLUMNS-1 ){
            echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        $column = ($column+1) % NUM_COLUMNS;
    }

    // Fill gaps
    if( $column>0 ){
        while( $column<NUM_COLUMNS ){
            echo '<td>—</td>';
            $column++;
        }
        echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '</table>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 print '<table border="2">';
 print '<tr>';
 $rowNum = 0;
 foreach($Cubicle as $cubicle){
     $rowNum++;

     if($rowNum % 4 == 0){ echo '<tr>'; }

     print '<td>';

     if($nodeStatus == '0'){
         printf('<a href= "#"  style="color: green; font-weight:bold" onClick="showDetails(\'%s\');">%s</a> ', $nodeId,$insert);
        }
        elseif($nodeStatus == '1'){
            printf('<a href= "#"  style="color: #AF7817; font-weight:bold" onClick="showDetails(\'%s\');">%s</a> ', $nodeId,$insert);
        }
        else{
            printf('<a href= "#"  style="color: RED; font-weight:bold" onClick="showDetails(\'%s\');">%s</a> ', $nodeId,$insert);
        }   

        print '</td>';

     if($rowNum % 4 == 0){ echo '</tr>'; }

    }
```